# JDBC MySQL execute SQL failures

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my code. I have a DB in MySQL which I use for processing. I referred to all the questions related to this exception. But none of them worked out for me. The problem is with the query I have used. When I make the query as

```sql
SELECT * FROM customers;
```

Then it works fine. But when I update it to following, exception will be thrown.

```sql
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id LIKE " + "'%" + consumerId + "%'
```

This is the exception I get.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.smart.data.customer.CustomerInfoProvider.findDetails(CustomerInfoProvider.java:81)
    at com.smart.data.customer.CustomerInfoProvider.provideRequiredCustomerDetails(CustomerInfoProvider.java:28)
    at com.smart.data.manipulator.Starter.main(Starter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:559)
    ... 22 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.smart.data.customer.CustomerInfoProvider.provideRequiredCustomerDetails(CustomerInfoProvider.java:30)
    at com.smart.data.manipulator.Starter.main(Starter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

```
package com.smart.data.customer;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: dulithdecozta
 * Date: 2/5/15
 * Time: 7:20 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class CustomerInfoProvider {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomerInfoProvider.class.getName());
    ResultSet customerResultSet = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    public void provideRequiredCustomerDetails(ArrayList customerIdArraylist) {
        for (int i = 0; i < customerIdArraylist.size(); i++) {
            try {
                customerResultSet = findDetails(customerIdArraylist.get(i).toString());
                try {
                    while (customerResultSet.next()) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Fullname : " + customerResultSet.getString("fullname"));
                            System.out.println("Consumer ID : " + customerResultSet.getString("customer_id"));
                            System.out.println("City : " + customerResultSet.getString("city"));
                            System.out.println("gender : " + customerResultSet.getString("gender"));
                            System.out.println("Occupation : " + customerResultSet.getString("occupation"));
                            System.out.println(i);
                            System.out.println("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    public ResultSet findDetails(String consumerId) throws IOException {
        // Load property file
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // Define an input stream
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/abc/Desktop/Jigi/database.properties"); // Path to the property file
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.debug("Exception encountered : File Not Found : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // load a properties file
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug("Exception encountered : A problem with the Input Stream : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(properties.getProperty("JDBC_DRIVER"));
            // log.debug("Connecting to database...!!");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty("DB_URL"), properties.getProperty("USER"), properties.getProperty("PASS"));
            //    log.debug("Creating statement...!");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id LIKE " + "'%" + consumerId + "%'");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the Exception in your question too

Comment: Is your version of the driver compatible with your MySQL version?

Comment: Yes it is compatible with it.

Comment: Make sure if MySQL service is running well. It seems that the DB daemon was down.

Comment: It is up and running well. I checked now.

Comment: It gives resutls upto some points and suddenly displays this exception.

Comment: A sidequest: if customer_id is numeric, do "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = " + consumerId

Comment: I didnt get you @Koshinae

Comment: LIKE is for text datatypes.

Comment: Yes I am using a VARCHAR for consumerId. LIKE could be used for those type of datatypes if I am not mistaken ?

Comment: Your query is pessimized (the opposite of optimized) for performance. (`'LIKE '%value%'` operations are *very* slow). It's possible your query is running too long and your connection's getting the boot.

Comment: Yes that would be the reason @OllieJones, because without using '*' in the query I just specified only the required column names and that displayed more results than earlier. However the exception was thrown as usual. Could you please tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: In the two queries you posted, one is on the `customer` table while the other is on the `customers` table (singular vs plural). Also, posting the table structure may help too. In mysql, run `show create table customer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Query returned the results without giving the exception.

```
package com.smart.data.customer;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: dulithdecozta
 * Date: 2/5/15
 * Time: 7:20 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class CustomerInfoProvider {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomerInfoProvider.class.getName());
    ResultSet customerResultSet = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    public void provideRequiredCustomerDetails(ArrayList customerIdArraylist) {
        for (int i = 0; i < customerIdArraylist.size(); i++) {
            try {
                customerResultSet = findDetails(customerIdArraylist.get(i).toString());
                try {
                    while (customerResultSet.next()) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Fullname : " + customerResultSet.getString("fullname"));
                            System.out.println("Consumer ID : " + customerResultSet.getString("customer_id"));
                            System.out.println("City : " + customerResultSet.getString("city"));
                            System.out.println("gender : " + customerResultSet.getString("gender"));
                            System.out.println("Occupation : " + customerResultSet.getString("occupation"));
                            System.out.println(i);
                            System.out.println("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    public ResultSet findDetails(String consumerId) throws IOException {
        // Load property file
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // Define an input stream
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/abc/Desktop/Jigi/database.properties"); // Path to the property file
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.debug("Exception encountered : File Not Found : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // load a properties file
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug("Exception encountered : A problem with the Input Stream : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(properties.getProperty("JDBC_DRIVER"));
            // log.debug("Connecting to database...!!");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty("DB_URL"), properties.getProperty("USER"), properties.getProperty("PASS"));
            //    log.debug("Creating statement...!");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id=" +consumerId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If my theory that your query takes too long is true, then you need to make the query take less time somehow.

You could try

```
 SELECT col1, col2, col3 
   FROM customer 
  WHERE customer_id LIKE '" +  consumerId + "%'"
  LIMIT 10
```

When you omit the leading `%` in the `LIKE` clause, you allow MySQL to use an index to find the right rows.

When you enumerate the columns you need from your query, you reduce the network traffic and allow MySQL to use some efficiencies in constructing the answer to your query.

When you say `LIMIT 10`, you avoid the possibility that MySQL will try to return the whole table if your user makes a mistake and requests an empty string.

You should also use a bind parameter for your `customerId` value. You can look up how to do this with JDBC.

Comment: Yes I checked.Thanks. But Still its not working. From your procedure it displayed lot of data than earlier. But still the exception is thrown after sometime. Anyway the cause is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could save those data into an array list and call that list when you need it. That would help you to prevent this exception. This is due to low response time of the query.